# iOS Record Cocos2Dx scene as video

Tags: ios, video, cocos2d-x, render

I'm looking for a way to save the cocos2dx scene as a video. Preferably would like this to happen in the background (animated scene not visible to user). 
I've looked at a few options:
Everplay - doesn't allow you to download the video file and requires the scene to be open and visible.
Kamcord - looks like it was discontinued or something and even when it did work, it doesn't look like it supported saving the video file to device
ReplayKit - requires user acceptance for the recording and I guess would require the scene to be open

I looked into saving the scene as an image frame by frame but haven't had much luck there.

Does anyone know of any options? Is there a way to access to frames and create the video with a pixelbuffer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Basically make a UIView extension

Swift 3:

```
public extension UIView {
    public func toImage() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 1.0)
        drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

You can grab the UIView 'picture' as many times as you need for your desired FPS. So say you want to do a full screen record at 20FPS, just create a timer and take a picture every 0.05 seconds. Once you have a sequence of images, you can combine them into a video using AVAssetWriter (you can just search images to video and find a ton of answers)